# Angular2 routing - manual url navigation

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a very simple app

My app.component.html looks like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/Test']">CLICK ME</a>
<div class="main-container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

My app.component.ts looks like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
    directives: [HomeComponent, TestComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/', component: HomeComponent, as: 'HomeComponent'},
  {path: '/test', component: TestComponent, as: 'Test'}
])

export class AppComponent { }
```

To navigate to my app, I go to

```
http://localhost/app
```

Which works perfect, it navigates me to my home component view as expected.
When I click the "CLICK ME" button, I am navigated to

```
http://localhost/app/test
```

And my test component is rendered as expected... HOWEVER, if I manually navigate to

```
http://localhost/app/test
```

My home component is loaded instead of my test component...what gives? How can I set up routing so that manual navigation to the test url actually returns my test component's view in the router outlet? Is this possible? I don't want to go to the landing page every time...

Comment: Have you set your base href in the index.html? it should be like the [docs suggest](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#base-href) `<base href="/">`

Comment: what is your angular2 version ?

Comment: beta17, base href is fine, I have a re-write rule to serve /app/index.html automatically which I thought was required to get PathLocationStrategy to work...but it does not...using node lite server

Answer (score 1):

In the new router especification you need something like this:

```
router.navigateByUrl("/app");
```

or

```
router.navigate(['HomeComponent'], {relativeTo: route});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to server configration. Your server may be redirecting to `index.html` for any error path or path after context.

You should configure your server to rewrite the path than redirect.

Provide more info on server code and server being used

Comment: you are correct, in my server web.config I have 

        <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*"/>
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/app/index.html"/>
        </rule>

Removing this line and testing - I now 404 after I refresh on the http://localhost/app/test link

Comment: As I said you need to configure the path for rewrite than redirect. Which server you are using that may help in suggesting how to rewrite

Comment: For Apache tomcat: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html

Comment: node lite..looking at similar stackoverflow questions it seems as though this re-write rule is correct. I just don't understand why it does not work with PathLocationStrategy routing

Answer (score 0):

*SOLVED* - My bootstrap was missing some content...I had

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  ROUTER_BINDINGS,
  bind(APP_BASE_HREF).toValue(location.pathname),
  bind(LocationStrategy).toClass(PathLocationStrategy )
  ]);
```

however this was incorrect, manually inputting:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  ROUTER_BINDINGS,
  bind(APP_BASE_HREF).toValue("/"),
  bind(LocationStrategy).toClass(PathLocationStrategy )
  ]);
```

Seemed to work. Thank you all for your help!